# categorize string from one column in another column - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with 3 columns. Column A contains titles on a lot of products, Column B contains all brand names and Column C contains models/series of all products. Column A got +2000 rows, column B got about 50 rows and Column C got about 200 rows. I want to create a new Column D, that categorizes if the Title in Column A includes Brand, Models or is Generic

**Example on my dataframe and desired result in Column D**

```
Column A        Column B   Column C    Column D
Running shoes   Nike       Airmax 2    Generic
Nike airmax 2   Adidas     All stars   Model/series
Airmax 2        Converse   Ultraboost  Model/series
Nike Shoes      Puma       Questar     Brand
```

If a row in column A contains brand and model I want Column D to categorize the row as model/serie. All rows in Column A that cannot get match with Brand or Models/series should be categorized as Generic.

I began trying with this:

```
df['Column D'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Column_b in x.Column_a, axis=1)
```

Here I got an error because column B has a lot less rows than Column A.

Then i wondered if looping even is the right way to do it or if i need to do a regex.

Any help on how to accomplish getting the desired Column D, would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain the output at row `Nike airmax 2`? How you got `Model/series` in the output?

Comment: I get that from Column C. So i want to Check if column A contains any of the brands i got in Column B or any of the models/series i got in Column C. If a row contains both Brands and model/Series i want the matching row in Column D to be 'Models/series'

Answer (score 2):

Use, [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to create a *boolean masks* `m1` where the truthy values in this mask corresponds to the condition where `Column A` contains the values from `Column B` in the similar manner create the *boolean mask* `m2`, then use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to select the values from choices based on the conditions based on `m1` and `m2`:

```
m1 = df['Column A'].str.contains('|'.join(df['Column B']), case=False)
m2 = df['Column A'].str.contains('|'.join(df['Column C']), case=False)

df['Column D'] = np.select(
    [m1 & m2, m1, m2], ['Model/series', 'Brand', 'Model/series'], 'Generic')
```

---

```
# print(df)
        Column A  Column B    Column C      Column D
0  Running shoes      Nike    Airmax 2       Generic
1  Nike airmax 2    Adidas   All stars  Model/series
2       Airmax 2  Converse  Ultraboost  Model/series
3     Nike Shoes      Puma     Questar         Brand
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
df['D'] = ['Brand' if x in df['B'].values else 'Model/Series' if x in df['C'].values else 'Generic' for x in df['A']]
```

I'm not 100% sure if your data can contain both a column B and a column C instance in a column A instance, but if so it's trivial to add another else if inside the list comprehension to catch both